# Can I detect when subtitle or audio tracks change in the iOS Chromecast SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

We're currently supporting track switching on our client just fine but I really need to know when a user switches to another subtitle or audio language (on the client) so that I can persist it going forward.

Is there a message that I can listen for that would alert me when this switch happens within the SDK (and hopefully gives me the language?)

Answer (score 2):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/ios_sender#status), your application should register a [`GCKMediaControlChannelDelegate`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/protocol_g_c_k_media_control_channel_delegate-p). If the `GCKMediaTextTrackStyle` of the current media changes, then all of the connected senders will be notified through both the [`mediaControlChannelDidUpdateMetadata:`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/protocol_g_c_k_media_control_channel_delegate-p#aa4806bab8620540325ae199c3574b034) and the [`mediaControlChannelDidUpdateStatus:`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/protocol_g_c_k_media_control_channel_delegate-p#a0fd482bf2cfa5a79bf1d443a07c10298) callbacks. Be noted that the list of tracks associated with the currently loaded media cannot be changed. If needed, you have to update the tracks information on the [`GCKMediaInformation`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_media_information) object and reload the media.